# Sudoers rpm command problem

Tags: sudo, sudoedit

Could you please help with below command. I need run without password prompt, But it requires password for user:

```
Cmnd_Alias user_RPM_YUM = /bin/rpm --allmatches -e $(rpm -qa blabla*) --nodeps
USER_USER DBS=(root) NOPASSWD: CODEDEPLOY_RPM_YUM
```

Comment: Perhaps this question reveals my ignorance about sudoers, but I don't see user_RPM_YUM referenced anywhere, and don't see the definition of CODEDEPLOY_RPM_YUM. Can you elaborate? Also, what is USER_USER? And which user is supposed to run the command?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.

Your `sudoers` `Cmnd_Alias` entry is trying to match the "`$( rpm ... )`" **character** string

The `sudo rpm ....` command sees the expanded `$( rpm ...)`, which is not the same. See `echo sudo rpm ...`. `bash` evaluates the "`$()`" before starting `sudo`.

Either simplify your `sudoers` `Cmnd_Alias` or write a program (not a script) providing this as a canned command.